# javascript function wouldn't fire until changed name - why?

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, onclick

I wrote a simple function to clear the input field on clicking a button. At first I had named the function `clear()`  and called it with oncick event in the button's html `<input type="button" id="clr"  onclick="clear()" value="Clr">`. My application uses other buttons that fire functions in the same manner no problem. However, on clicking the "Clr" button nothing would happen. I tried moving this script from the `<head>` to the `<body>`, tried making the button id different from the function name, etc... Finally, changing the function name from `clear()` to `clr()` made it work.

I checked javascript reserved words list and "clear" is not one of them... why would my function not fire when named `clear()`?

Whole code for reference:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
   <title>変換天才</title>
   

 <script>


 //myriad converter function help from Stack Overflow user paxdiablo
 function makeNum(num) {
    num = num.replace(/,/g,"");      //remove commas
    var markers = "万億兆京該秭穣溝澗正載極";
    var result = "";

 //regroup in myriads
    while (num.length > 4) {
        if (markers.length == 0) {
            result = "(?)" + num.substr(num.length-4) + result;
        } else {
            result = markers.substr(0, 1) + num.substr(num.length-4) + result;
            markers = markers.substr(1);
        }
        num = num.substr(0, num.length-4);
   }
     return num + result;
 }

 function convert(){
 
 var innum = document.getElementById("input").value;
 var parsnum = (innum.replace(/,/g,""));
 if (isNaN(parseInt(parsnum)) == true) {
 document.getElementById("converted").innerHTML = "Please enter valid number.";

 }
 else {
 var myriad = makeNum(innum);
 document.getElementById("converted").innerHTML = myriad ;
 
   }
 }

  

 function clr(){
 document.getElementById("input").value = "";
 document.getElementById("converted").innerHTML = "";
 }
 
 
 </script>

  </head>

  <body>
 <div><p>Enter a large whole number.</p></div>
 <input type="text" id="input"/>
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Convert" onclick="convert()">
 <br>
 <input type="button" id="xthou" onclick="xThou()" value="thousand">
 <input type="button" id="xmil" onclick="xMil()" value="million">
 <input type="button" id="xbil" onclick="xBil()" value="billion">
 <br>
 <input type="button" id="xtril" onclick="xTril()" value="trillion">
 <input type="button" id="xquad" onclick="xQuad()" value="quadrillion">
 <input type="button" id="clr"  onclick="clr()" value="Clr"> 
 <br><br>
 <div id="commaed"></div>
 <div id="converted"></div>



  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The confusion here (and documented in that other question) is one of many reasons not to put javascript inline in the HTML.  Check out [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/unobtrusive-javascript-important).

Comment: @CraigSuchanec Thank you for the question link - it seems that it may be an issue of scope in the end - the answer is very helpful!